# Connecting a vent fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, vent

I have a new vent fan, but no instructions.  The old van had a light and fan, and I have two wall switches for it.  The new fan has a light and fan as well.

In my ceiling I have a black, white, red, and ground.

The new fan has a black, a white, a white and blue (both labeled 'light'), and a neutral.

Any suggestions on how to set this up?  Thank you,
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the "neutral" that you listed for the new fan/light is NOT a neutral, it is a ground. The standard colors are:

- White = Neutral (you have one in the existing wiring, 2 in the new unit)
- Green & bare = Ground (you have bare in the existing wiring, green in the new unit)
- The other colors (black & red in the existing wiring, black & blue in the new unit) are all Hot.

1 - Wire nut all White neutrals together. Your existing wiring has one neutral because the fan & light are on the same circuit so they can share neutral.

2 - Wire nut Green & bare ground together.

3 - Wire nut Blacks together for fan switch.

4 - Wire nut Blue to Red for light switch.

Comment: Thank you!  I realized after posting I was using ground and neutral interchangeably, which obviously is not the case.